# Find the best way to buy p Product from limit x Vendors

Tags: algorithm

I **have to buy** 100 Products ( or p Products) from 20 Vendors ( or v Vendors). Each Vendors have all of these Products, but they sell different Price.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaupb.jpg << Image description. Sorry, I can not post Image because I'm a new user.]

I want to find the best price to get 100 Products. Asume that there is no Shipping Cost.
There are v^p ways. And I will get only one way that have best Price.
The problem seem to be easy if there is no requirement: LIMIT number of Vendors to x in the Orders because of Time Delivery ( or Some reasons).

So, the problem is: Find the best way to buy p Product from limit x Vendors ( There are v Vendors , x<=v).

I can generate all Combination of Vendors( There are C(v,x) combinations) and compare the Total Price. But There are so many combinations . (if there are 20 Vendors, there are around 185k combinations).
I stuck at this idea. 
Someone has same problem , pls help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pivot some columns.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your requirements are. Do you have to buy *any* 100 products? - in which case find the lowest price in the whole matrix and buy 100 of those. Do you have to buy *one of each of 100* products? - in which case, on each row buy from whoever is cheapest. A (smaller) complete example, say, 4 products and 3 vendors, would help.

Comment: Hello leppie, Can you describe what you mean ? I don't understand your idea. Thank you very much

Comment: Hello AakasM, I **have to buy** all 100 products. But limit the number of Vendors. For example: I have to buy all Products, But I want to  buy these products From maximum 5 Vendors only.

Comment: With the image above: 
If the limit Provider is 1 : Then I will choose : P1,P2,P3 =>V6 . Total Cost = 59$

If the limit Provider is 2 : Then I will choose: P1->V2, P2->V2,P3->V2, Total cost= 58$
If the limit Provider is 3: I will chose P1->V3,P2->V6, P3-> V2 Or V5. Total cost= 57.5$

Comment: Are you looking for optimal solution? Or heuristical one, which will be relatively good one, though not guaranteed to be optimal?

Comment: I need a heristical one, which should give me optimal one.f I don't have any heristic, I have to do brute-force to scan All ways to get optimal solution. Do you have any heristic? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same exact problem anyone can explain to me how to that in python. I am new programmer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to the non-metric [k-center problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center) (cities = products, warehouses = vendors), which is NP-hard.

I would try mixed integer programming. Here's one formulation.

```
minimize c(i, j) y(i, j)  # cost of all of the orders
subject to
for all i: sum over j of y(i, j) = 1  # buy each product once
for all i, j: y(i, j) <= z(j)  # buy products only from chosen vendors
sum over j of z(j) <= x  # choose at most x vendors
for all i, j: 0 <= y(i, j) <= 1
for all j: z(j) in {0, 1}
```

The interpretation of the variables is that `i` is a product, `j` is a vendor, `c(i, j)` is the cost of product `i` from vendor `j`, `y(i, j)` is `1` if we buy product `i` from vendor `j` and `0` otherwise, `z(j)` is `1` is we buy from vendor `j` at all and `0` otherwise.

There are [many](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/milpf.html) free mixed integer program solvers available.

Comment: That sounds good for me. I am reviewing the k-center Problem.

Comment: @MarkDixons the link Per suggested is metric k-center, but in your case I don't think is a metric version, so approximation algorithms are not good for you, best choice for you is heuristic or as you mentioned brute force algorithm.

Comment: Can someone explain that in pure python

Answer (score 3):

**Not Correct as shown by @Per the structure lacks optimal substructure**

My assumptions are as follows, from the master table you need to create a sub list which has only "x" vendor columns, and "Best Price" is the "Sum" of all the prices.

Use a dynamic programming approach
What you do is define two functions, `Picking (i,k)` and `NotPicking(i,k)`.
What it means is getting the best with ability to pick vendors from 1,.. i with maximum of k vendors.

```
Picking (1,_) = Sum(All prices)
NotPicking (1,_) = INF
Picking (_,0) = INF
NotPicking (_,0) = INF

Picking (i,k) = Min (Picking(i-1,k-1) + NotPicking(i-1,k-1)) - D (The difference you get because of having this vendor)
NotPicking (i,k) = Min (Picking(i-1,k) + NotPicking(i-1,k))
```

You just solve it for a `i` from 1 to V and `k` from 1 to X

You calculate the difference by maintaining for each picking the whole product list, and calculating the difference.

Comment: You should be able to get several products from the same vendor. I'm not sure how the above makes it possible if Picking always forwards a reduced number of available vendors, that goes from k to k-1 unconditionally. Seems like there's the same kind of problem with i.

Comment: Picking means - You are selecting the `i` th vendor, hence you can only select **a maximum of** k-1 vendors. 
NotPicking means - You are **not** selecting the 'i' th vendor , hence you still can select **k** vendors. 
Knowing which product to get from whom can be done while you are updating the product list.

Comment: That DP **doesn't work** because this problem doesn't have the kind of optimal substructure you need. Specifically, `D` depends on which vendors you have chosen previously, and there are i-1 choose k-1 possibilities.

Comment: I am not storing a single `D`, for each of the (i,k) pair value I will be storing a separate array of the selected prices for `p` products.

Comment: In general, every single one of the (i,k) subsolutions has something to recommend it over the others, given that the other vendors have not been examined yet. You're not going to get this to work without brute force.

Comment: Thank you, Manyu And All friends and supporters.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Greedy Approach. Since you have a limitation on the vendors ( you need to use at least x of the total v vendors). That means you need to choose at least 1 product from each vendor of the x ... And here's an example solution:

For each vendor in v, sort the products by price, then you will have "v" sets of sorted prices. Now you can pick the min of these sets and sort again, producing a new set of "v" products, containing only the cheapest ones.

Now, if p <= v, then pick the first p items and you are done, otherwise pick all v items and repeat the same logic until you reach p.

Comment: read again, you have to buy from at most x vendors (upper and not lower limit).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked this out and verified, but I guess it might work. Try this:

Add two more columns called "Highest Price" and "Lowest Price" to the table and generate data for it: they should hold the highest and lowest price for each product amongst all vendors.
Also add another column, called "Range" which should hold the (highest price - lowest price).

Now do this 100 (p) times:

1. Pick the row with highest range. Buy the product with least price on
   that row. Once bought, mark that cell as 'bought' (maybe set null).
2. Recalculate lowest price, range for that row (ignoring cells marked as 'bought').

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Hungarian algorithm is not the answer to your question unless you did not wanted to put a limit on vendors.

The algorithm you are looking for is [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

There are many [available implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Implementations) of it on the web.

Comment: not really - the hungarian algorithm is about perfect matching, while that's not the case here. Best solution here could be all the products are both from the same vendor.

Comment: yeah. The main Problem is : limit the number of Vendors. And the Main objective is: minimum total cost.

Comment: oops my bad. I missed such an essential thing about the question.